# reverse bit operations

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, reverse

Just a quick one here, is it possible to find the original values of aValue and bValue from  i? and if so how?

Thanks.

```
uint i = Convert.ToUInt32((aValue << 2) & 0x300) | bValue;
```

Comment: Of course, in general no. But if you know that `aValue` and `bValue` (what types are they?) were in specific ranges, then maybe the values can be recovered.

Comment: are you trying to make some cyphering or hashing algorithm? If so, there are many alternatives, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen avalue can be 0x00-0xff and bvalue can be 0x00-0x09.

Comment: In that case you can recover `bValue` fully (with `i & 0xf`). For `aValue` you can only recover the two most significant bits.

Comment: First you lose two bits due to the shift, then you lose everything *but* two bits from the AND, and then you lose everything else due to the OR. You can't even get a single bit back, unless `bValue & 0x300` is guaranteed to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to find *the* pair of values from `i`, because multiple pairs could produce identical results.

It is easy to see if you consider an example where all bits of `bValue` are set. Then all bits of `i` will be set as well, regardless of the value of `aValue`. Now consider the situation when every odd bit of `aValue` is set, every even bit of `bValue` is set, and also the least significant bit of `bValue` is set. Again, the result will have all its bits set, for a very different pair of `aValue` and `bValue`.

```
aValue=00110011, bValue=11111111 ---> i=11111111
aValue=10110000, bValue=11111111 ---> i=11111111
aValue=00000000, bValue=11111111 ---> i=11111111
aValue=01010101, bValue=10101011 ---> i=11111111
```

Answer (score 0):

Many values can produce the same result.

Even if you had one of the values, you couldn't still be sure about the other one, not always, because information is lost during the operation, which is irreversible.